# Data fetching really slow from webservice

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, core-data, fetch

I have the following webserivce.

```
"club": {

    "staff": [ … ],
    "trainingen": [ … ],
    "team": [
        {
            "name": "Baerts Lennert",
            "number": "0",
            "position": "Doelman",
            "birthdate": "1996-09-01",
            "red_cards": 0,
            "yellow_cards": 0,
            "news": [
                {
                    "nid": "1158",
                    "player_id": 1
                },
                {
                    "nid": "1148",
                    "player_id": 1
                },

            ]
        },
```

I'm getting this with the following method.

```
+ (NSArray *)getPlayNewsWithIndex:(int)index
{
    NSLog(@"index is hier %d",index);
    NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.krcgenk.be/mobile/json/request/club/type/ipad"];
    NSLog(@"log1");
    NSArray *arr = [[self executeGenkFetch:request] valueForKeyPath:@"club.team"];
    NSLog(@"log2");
    NSArray *arr2 = [[arr objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"news"];
    NSLog(@"log3");
    return arr2;
}
```

After it logs "log1". It takes a while when the function continues. My question is now, how this is possible?

**EDIT**

This is my executeGenkFetch

```
+ (NSDictionary *)executeGenkFetch:(NSString *)query
{
    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", query];
    query = [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // NSLog(@"[%@ %@] sent %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), query);
    NSData *jsonData = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:query] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *results = jsonData ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error] : nil;
    if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] JSON error: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error.localizedDescription);
    // NSLog(@"[%@ %@] received %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), results);
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the time gap in between logs 1 and 2 is larger than you expected?

Comment: My webrequest doesn't take long, the time between log1 and 2 takes a very long time.

Comment: The only thing happening between those log statements is `executeGenkFetch`.  If you don't think the web request is what's taking time, go inside that method and measure whatever happens there.

Comment: @Ivopeeters: Isn't `executeGenkFetch:` what does the web request? I assume so since it rakes an URL as input and returns your JSON structure. On the other hand, according to Google the only thing _anyone_ _ever_ does with `executeGenkFetch:` is to ask questions about it on StackOverflow. Is it a standard API?

Comment: First of all guys, thank you for your help. But I have 10 other functions like this. And they are not going slow. The only differnce between those methods are that I didn't do something like this [[arr objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"news"];

Comment: I see you've commented out the logging inside `executeGenkFetch:` but my guess would be you'd see the same delay between those `sent` and `received` logs as `log1` and `log2`. You are also doing a lot of redundant string creation in that method FWIW.

Comment: Thank you guys for your reactions. But do you maybe know how i can fix it?

Comment: Run this code using Instruments, specifically the Time Profiler instrument. That will tell you *exactly* how much time each line is taking. Then you can attack the problem with actual data.